# Does citation count include cites from arxiv

Tags: google-scholar, bibliometrics

I was wondering, suppose I have an arxiv paper citing my paper, does Researchgate or google scholar count it as if my paper was cited?

What if there are two versions (arxiv and peer reviewed) and lets say the citations do not all match, what then? (e.g. I would think counting at most once everything that is in either version is best. But, what actually happens?)

Comment: Why are you bothered about the citation count?

Comment: "Does citation count include cites from arxiv" One answer is that there is no "citation count" in absolute terms. Different systems count different things and there is no (and never will be) a general definition.

Comment: @Coder mainly curious.

Comment: @Dirk makes sense, how do the big guys (google?) deal with that then?

Answer (score 4):

Google scholar counts any citation from anything their algorithms identify as a technical document. These are not limited to "known" or approved publications. Thus these include citations from papers on arxiv.

I don't know about researchgate.

Comment: Now Researchgate is included too and if you upload your preprint on both arxiv and Researchgate it will show as separate documents. Stupid!